# Cannont acces folder created in program

Tags: java, excel, directory

I am creating an inventory program for my dad's small business and I have a problem with accessing  a folder. Before the rest of the program runs, it checks if a folder called "Dos Amantes Inventory" exists, and if not it will create it. Then it checks if there is an excel workbook in that folder, however, I run into an access denied error here trying to look inside that folder. How do I rectify this?
I know it doesn't look pretty at all, and I'll clean up later, just want to get it working first, spent way too long on this already. Thanks in advance

```
public static boolean goodToGo;

//get user's desktop path
public static String desktopPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Dos Amantes Inventory";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{



    if(!new File(desktopPath).exists()){
        FileManager.createPath();

        if(!new File(desktopPath + "/" + Ingredients.workbookName).exists()){
            FileManager.createWorkbook(desktopPath);
            goodToGo = true;
        } else {
            goodToGo = true;
        }
    }else if(!new File(desktopPath + "/" + Ingredients.workbookName).exists()){
        FileManager.createWorkbook(desktopPath);
        goodToGo = true;
    }else {
        goodToGo = true;
    }

    if(goodToGo){
        start();
    }

}


//methods from FileManager class
public static void createPath(){
    new File(Inventory.desktopPath + "/Dos Amantes Inventory").mkdirs();
}

public static void createWorkbook(String filePath) throws IOException{
    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filePath));
    WritableSheet wsheet = workbook.createSheet(Ingredients.workbookName, 0);
}
```

Comment: In what scenario are you not "good to go"?

Comment: I tried to make a loop that would not allow such a case. If there is not folder or file, make both, good to go. If there is a folder, but no file, make one, good to go. If both exist, good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are actually creating the folder. If that is the problem, you might try this:

```
File folder = new File(desktopPath);
if (!folder.exists()) {
     folder.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Oh shoot, forgot to add the FileManager class methods